# What is the difference between OSS and RDS

Tags: relational-database, cloud-object-storage

It seems i do not fully understand the difference between OSS and RDS.

Both can store data, RDS is good for structured data, and OSS seems to be able to store most types of data (and should be able to store structured data as well).

So why do we need to provide two service？

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, structured data storage services like MySQL, SQL server are still very popular. If any migration from traditional IT structure， that is very useful
Above must be an very import point for your question.